# Run-time error 1004 when using Offset function

Tags: vba

How do I retrieve the cell next to the one that has been defined? Cell "A2" stores `AT` and I want to display `Austria` which i have displayed in cell "B2" instead of `AT`. I need this functionality in a For loop.

```
AT  Austria
IT  Italy
FR  France
```

I need to do the For loop using AT (for other purposes) but i want to write away the country name (Austria or Italy etc)

The macro below gives run-time error 424 Object required.

```
Sub test()
    Dim country
    Dim country_list
    Dim counter

    country_list = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")
    counter = 1

    For Each country In country_list
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = country.Offset(0, 1).Value
        counter = counter + 1
    Next country
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use set for this to work the way you want.

```
Set country_list = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")
```

It returns error sine your variable was not assigned an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(0,1).Value
```

As it is right now, you're not passing a valid *range* to the `Range(country)...` method.  You have defined `country` to be the *value* of the cell "A2".

The 1004 error means that you are attempting to access a range by address which either does not exist, or cannot be accessed.  In this case, the range simply doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks David, that helps. However, i still want to make the reference to country, as in the For loop i cannot say "A2" because it can also be "A3" etc

Comment: so, what do i need to do for the following to work: Country.Offset(0,1).Value

Comment: You need to show more of your code. `Country` must be a valid Range object at a minimum.

Comment: thanks David... i changed my Question (providing more code) and i got the answer in the meantime. thanks for your help!